# UIBarButtonItem is not clickable

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, chromecast

I write an iOS app in Swift able to cast videos to chromecast. I try to add mini controller at the bottom of the phone screen. Here is a fragment of my code:

```
    ...
    var castContainerVC = GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().createCastContainerControllerForViewController(self.navigationController)
    castContainerVC.miniMediaControlsItemEnabled = true
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds
    UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow?.rootViewController = castContainerVC
    UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    ...
```

When I run this app, I can see mini controller, but when I click on my menu navigation bar button, nothing happens (It worked before I added this code). I don't have this problem with the other two navigation bar button items. I suspect that something gets wrong when I try to assign new rootViewController, but I don't know how could I fix it.

Comment: Have you tried the alternate way to add the mini controller directly to your existing view controller by using createMiniMediaControlsViewController to create a GCKUIMiniMediaControlsViewController instance and then adding it to the container view controller as a subview?

Comment: Thank you, it works! But unfortunelly a text in MiniMediaControlsViewController doesn't fit within its width. Is there way to modify MiniMediaControlsViewController's components? In API I have found only an option to customize the buttons. On google site is an information that you can customize widgets with appearance protocol, but I have no idea how to get an access for example to miniMediaControlsViewController's title Label.

Comment: @LeonNicholls.. I can add the minimediacontrols however, first time I start it, it does not connect to chrome cast which is already connected by me...and when I click on mini controller, it opens expandedviewcontroller, and first time it shows "Casting to Living room", which is default text.